# I want to check network connectivity status and got stuck while using getActiveNetworkInfo method which is depricated

Tags: android, kotlin

I basically wanted to know how to check internet connectivity status in android after the deprication of `NetworkInfo` methods in API level 29.

i have tried calling `getActiveNetworkInfo` method but it is depricated, any quick help is highly appreciated.

i have got  stuck at this point..

```
fun verifyIfNetworkAvailable(activity: AppCompatActivity):Boolean{

        var connectivityManager = activity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
            var networkInfo = connectivityManager.isDefaultNetworkActive

            return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected

        }
```

by the way i am using Kotlin.

Comment: Please change the topic / title to `check internet connectivity status in android after the deprication of NetworkInfo methods in API level 29`

Answer (score 0):

go ahead with this one, PS not mine,

```
fun isWiFiConnected(context: Context): Boolean {
val connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
return if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    val network = connectivityManager.activeNetwork
    val capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network)
    capabilities != null && (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI))
} else {
    connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo.type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`NetworkInfo` class is Deprecated  in API level 29. So the methods which returns a instance for `NetworkInfo` are deprecated also. To move further with newer API you can follow the Doc which says :-

> Callers should instead use the ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback API to learn about connectivity changes, or switch to use ConnectivityManager#getNetworkCapabilities or ConnectivityManager#getLinkProperties to get information synchronously.

Please Check the official Doc for [Network Info](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html) and [Connectivity Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager) for use.

Answer (score 0):

You can check internet connection like that. if you do not want to check device connectitivty.

step 1 add your async class

```
public class YourInternetCheckerClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>
{
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids)
    {
        try
        {
            InetAddress ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");
            return !ipAddr.equals("");

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("GCInternetChecker", e.toString());
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

step 2 call this async task this is a function.

```
  private boolean checkInternetConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            return new GCInternetChecker().execute().get();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

step 3 check internet before call your service

```
if (this.checkInternetConnection())
{
    //call service
}
else
{
 //handle no internet. Toast or dialog box.
}
```